# AWS Data Pipeline didn't showing EC2 instance role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline

I am trying to get data from S3 to Dynamodb using AWS Data Pipeline. The issue I am facing is that my "Data Pipeline" wasn't showing EC2 instance role even though I have created one in the IAM. I have created default roles for Pipeline and EC2.
[image: Pipeline Role]
[image: EC2 Role]
[image: Here is the picture of Pipeline]

You can see in the picture that Pipeline Role is showing but the EC2 role didn't appear. I have refreshed several times and recreated Pipeline but didn't get the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem too.
I think you need to create an [instance profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html).

[Data Pipeline's doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-iam-roles.html#dp-iam-roles-new) says that you should choose `EC2 Role for Data Pipeline` use case to create a resource role. But if you do that, instance profile won't be created.
Instead, you need to choose `EC2` use case and attach policies to the role. Instance profile will be created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by creating a standard EC2 role for the Instance Role and not using the Data Pipeline option while making the Resource role. Creating the EC2 Resource role using the Data Pipeline option seems to be deprecated.